# Is the number picker available in Jetpack compose Android native (Not a 3rd party library)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is the number picker available in Jetpack compose Android native (Not a 3rd party library)

[image]

I want to build like above number picker in jetpack compose

Comment: No, You can find available components here. [Material 2](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary) and [Material 3](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no spec for it on Material.io so this is out of scope of the material library.

Reference : [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288609613)